# Правильность употребления глагола

Tags: морфология

Можно ли выразиться так:
"Тщедушный птенец растёт в орла"
Или необходимо употребить: "вырастает"?

Comment: Объясните смысл этой фразы. От смысла будет зависеть и выбор глагола.

Comment: Маленький птенец превращается в большую птицу, мне достаточно знать, что "растёт" -  допустимое применение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отвечаю с учетом реплики в комментариях.

> Маленький птенец превращается в большую птицу, мне достаточно знать,
> что "растёт" - допустимое применение

Это не совсем то, о чем я спрашивал, но ладно. Можно предположить, что контекст здесь все-таки имеется. Так вот, в таком контексте фраза представляется стилистически (если не семантически) ошибочной.
Есть закрепившееся разговорное выражение типа "растет в папу" (маму, или там дедушку-бабушку). Более ходовой его вариант - "пошел в папу", можно считать синонимом. Значение его то, что ребенок похож на своего родственника, причем конкретного.
Но это, как я понимаю, совсем не то, что вы вкладываете в свою фразу.

Так что какая-то правка фразе явно требуется хотя бы из соображений ликвидации двусмысленности. Но, боюсь, ваша замена "растет" на "вырастает" тут тоже не сильно поможет. По тем же причинам: двусмысленность остается. Я бы вообще заменил "растет в кого" на "становится кем" (***"птенец растет и становится орлом"***), но тут тоже могут возникнуть вопросы в связи с контекстом.

Плюс ко всему - сомнения насчет употребления слова "тщедушный" (болезненный, хилый, где-то даже "нежизнеспособный"). Соответствует ли оно авторской мысли? Не думаю...